# How to filter inside a variable in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate **the total product (in units and €) that has been purchased, but we have not subsequently sold**.

For this I have a product table (dim_product), which is related through [product_id] with a sales table (fact_sale_order_line) and a purchase table (fact_purchase_order_line).

To calculate the units, I have no problem. However, I don't know how to calculate the costs of **those** units. That cost is given by the purchase_amount field. This is what I have tried, but with this I'm calculating the € of the total units purchased (and **I want only the units that we have bought and then we have not sold**):

```
€_enero_2021 = 
var units_purchased =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_purchase_order_line[product_quantity]),
    AND(
        fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]>=20210101,
        fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]<=20210131
    )
)

var units_sold =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order_line[product_quantity]),
    AND(
        fact_sale_order_line[order_date_id]>=20210101,
        fact_sale_order_line[order_date_id]<=20210131
    )
)

var units_purchased_not_sold =
units_purchased - units_sold


var euros_purchase =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_purchase_order_line[purchase_amount]),
    AND(
        fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]>=20210101,
        fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]<=20210131
    )
)


var result =
IF(
    units_purchased_not_sold <=0,
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(fact_purchase_order_line[purchase_amount]),
        AND(
            fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]>=20210101,
            fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id]<=20210131
        )
    )
)

return result
```

To have the result I am looking for, in the last variable I should write something like this:

```
var result = 
IF(
        unidades_compradas_no_vendidas <=0,
        BLANK(),
        CALCULATE(
            euros_compras,
            unidades_compradas_no_vendidas <=0
        )
    )
```

However that does not work because I am using the CALCULATE with variables.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX is much easier when you use dimension tables and building block measures.

Define these measures individually:

```
[Units_Purchased] = SUM ( fact_purchase_order_line[product_quantity] )

[Units_Sold] = SUM ( fact_sale_order_line[product_quantity] )

[Euros_Purchased] = SUM ( fact_purchase_order_line[purchase_amount] )
```

Then your current measure could be rewritten as:

```
CALCULATE (
    IF ( 
        [Units_Purchased] > [Units_Sold],
        [Euros_Purchased]
    ),
    fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id] >= 20210101,
    fact_purchase_order_line[order_date_id] <= 20210131
)
```

This doesn't answer your question but serves as an intermediate point to what I'll suggest next.

---

Assuming you have proper dimension tables set up, you should be able to define the measure

```
Euros_Purchased_Not_Sold =
CALCULATE (
    [Euros_Purchased],
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( dimension_product[unit_id] ),
        [Units_Purchased] > [Units_Sold]
    )
)
```

Then you can wrap this measure with your date filtering to get the specific month you want:

```
€_enero_2021 =
CALCULATE (
    [Euros_Purchased_Not_Sold],
    dimension_date[year] = 2021,
    dimension_date[month] = 1
)
```

Variables are fixed once defined but you can reuse measures in whatever context you like. The key lesson here is to break things up into components.